# terraform provide a list of available images in your cloud

Tags: terraform-provider-openstack

Is there any command that can provide you with a list of images available in your infrastructure
Something like: `terraform show providers images` ?

Comment: you want to import images

Comment: The images are already uploaded and available via the browser so I can deploy whichever one I want.Is there any command in terraform that I can use in order to also have the images listed?